# Change base href using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Can I change the  href by javascript?

I use the following code in  but it doesn't work:

```
<base href="/" />
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function setbasehref(basehref) { 
 var thebase = document.getElementsByTagName("base"); 
 thebase[0].href = basehref; 
} 
//setbasehref("/");
setbasehref("http://newurl.com");
</script>
```

Comment: In fact it works. I tested it with Firefox 3.5.3 and Web Developer extension (View Generated Source Code). Could you please provide more informations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("base");
```

Do you have an element of type "base"?

Perhaps you could try grabbing the element by its ID attribute?

```
 document.getElementById("YourHyperlinksID");
```

Good luck